# iOS How to use MPReomoteControl in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing music player through SwiftUI and I have sample code written in Swift5.

I want to use remotecontrol to change the playback position while playing the music.

However, I don't know how to use @objc function in SwiftUI.

So '#selector' occurs problem..

I appreciate if you teach me how to convert Swift5 code to SwiftUI.

```
   func setUpRemoteTransparentControls(){
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget{
            event in
            if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
                self.play_pause()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget{
            event in
            if audioPlayer.isPlaying{
                self.pauseSong()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget{
            event in
            if audioPlayer.isPlaying{
                self._forward()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget{
            event in
            if audioPlayer.isPlaying{
                self._backward()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeThumbSlider(_:)))
    }
    
    @objc func changeThumbSlider(_ event: MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus{
        audioPlayer.currentTime = event.positionTime
        return .success
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true;
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { event in
        if let event = event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = event.positionTime
        }
        return .success
    }
```

Comment: Я проверил у себя на мак и все работает. Знаю, что поздно, но вдруг пригодиться комоу-то еще.